# Why isn't Luke's lightsaber red?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

According to the [Ahsoka novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_(novel)) (written by E. K. Johnston), Kyber crystals choose Force users and present themselves to their desired owner, but dark siders don’t experience this same connection to the crystals. The only way the Sith and other dark side Force users can collect kyber crystals is by stealing them or plundering them off the bodies of their fallen foes. Even if a dark sider were to acquire a kyber crystal from a green or blue saber, the act of bending the crystal to their will in a new lightsaber will cause the crystal to “bleed,” turning it red.

Anakin's second lightsaber was used by Vader to amputate Mace Windu, kill dozens padawans at Jedi Temple, slay all Separatist leaders and fight Obi-Wan on Mustafar. After dismembering Anakin in Episode III, Kenobi picked the saber up  and 19 years later, he gives Anakin's second lightsaber to Luke and the blade is still blue. Shouldn't it be red now?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Crystals don't change colour while inside a lightsaber

This is something that Pablo Hidalgo seems to get asked on an almost weekly basis on Twitter; [here's](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/829340022801211392) just one of his *many* (identical, with slight variations on wording) responses:

[image]

> **@JosuSen** after reading about cristals in Ahsoka,does it mean remasterd ROTS would show Anakin killing youngsings with a red lightsaber?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** no, crystals don't change automatically. It's an exertion of will during the construction of a lightsaber that does it.

For Anakin's lightsaber to turn red, he'd have had to disassemble and reassemble it, forming a new bond with the crystal in the process; obviously he didn't exactly have time for that while right in the middle of Order 66, but presumably he'd have gotten around to it afterwards, if everything had gone according to plan.

Comment: They retconned themselves into a corner.

Comment: @Terriblefan But if they keep using the same line, eventually we'll accept it as truth, right?

Comment: I love how it all comes down to "an exertion of will"

Comment: Assuming Anakin managed to retain his lightsaber, would he really decide to disassemble and reassemble his lightsaber just so he can change the blade's color?

Comment: Dear god this is dumb. Not you, Jason. Cannon is. This is the modern midichlorian.

Comment: @Ellesedil To make a clean break from his past (something that seems important to him, and which he struggles with, as seen in *Lords of the Sith* and the *Darth Vader* comics), I could see him doing that

Comment: @Terriblefan I haven't read the novel in question, but based on the summary in OP's question, I'm not sure I understand the issue, let alone why this answer doesn't address your concerns. It was already canon, I believe, that the construction of a lightsaber requires the use of the Force; and obviously, since General Grievous can wield four lightsabers at once, it's canon that the Force is *not* required to *use* a lightsaber. So why would the "bend it to their will" (explicitly using the Force) concept apply to murders committed using a lightsaber in the first place?

Comment: @KyleStrand The entire "kyber crystals are alignment identifiers" business is a ridiculous retcon. The followup of "they only change color when you use the Force to assemble the lightsaber, not the dozens of times you exert the Force on your lightsaber in every fight." is the ridiculous retcon of the ridiculous retcon to explain their way out of the resulting corner.

Comment: @Terriblefan, seeing as your comment has (at this writing) more upvotes than this answer *or* the question, I think you're onto something.  :)

Comment: Sidious gave Vader a red lightsaber identical to his old one.

Comment: @Terriblefan Again, I don't understand the "corner"; based on the question here, the summary of the "bleeding" idea [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal), and the author's own comments, it sounds like the whole idea is that the specific event that makes the crystals turn red is the *construction* of a lightsaber by a Sith. Is there something missing from these summaries that indicates why you, the OP here, and, apparently, many other readers would take the novel's text to indicate that any use of Sith power while wielding a lightsaber would turn the crystals?

Comment: As for the complaint that the crystals shouldn't act as alignment identifiers--why not? It seems they effectively already do serve this role in the films.

Comment: It's already canon that crystals chose their users through the Force; we saw this in the Clone Wars series, in Rebels, and in Ahsoka. It's not exactly surprising to know that the Dark Side, which tries to impose its will on the Force rather than following the will Of the Force, has a way of forcing that connection. Someone said that this was the "Modern Midichlorian", and they're right - fans not paying attention, not listening, and strawmanning a piece of canon they've taken an irrational disliking to.

Comment: @KyleStrand The complaint is that the explanation is perceived (by some fans) as being [plot spackle](https://theeditinghart.com/2014/09/03/plot-spackle/). It's not that (again, some) people don't understand the explanation, it's that they find it an unsatisfying resolution to what looks like a plot hole. Or, in other words, complaining about Star Wars is the only thing Star Wars fans like more than Star Wars itself

Comment: @JasonBaker Thanks. I just don't understand what it is about Ahsoka that makes some readers perceive a plot hole in the first place.

Comment: @KyleStrand It's not about Ahsoka. It's about Disney declaring a sensible system - lightsaber colors coming from a crystal's color (and noting that there were *several* crystals in a lightsaber), which doesn't change -  obsolete in favor of  alignment sensing semi-sentient pieces of rock.

And I'll quit complaining about Star Wars when they make KOTOR canon again. ;)

Comment: @Ellesedil why would it be so ridiculous for Vader to disassemble and reassemble his light saber?  Sith do all kind of things to instill terror in their opponents.   He doesn't need his suit to be black and menacing, and he didn't need to take the name Vader --  Sheev could have named him Darth Fluffybunny.   And he has a lot of time in his palace on Mustafar.  And maybe lightsabers need to be disassembled and reassembled occasionally for maintenance anyhow.    Of all the things to complain about, I don't personally have a problem with this one.   (Also, IJAM)

Comment: @Terriblefan Ah, okay--the issues with the number of crystals per lightsaber and the sentience of the crystals were not clear to me from prior comments, and I can see how those changes might rankle. It sounds like they *haven't* changed the fact that lightsaber colors come from a crystal's color, but the idea that crystal colors can change *is* new; is that correct? And, out of curiosity, is there anything that was previously canon that explicitly indicated that crystal colors *don't* change?

Comment: @KyleStrand [The colors stayed the same regardless of who was using (and assembling) them, and putting multiple in the same saber resulted in mixed colors.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal#Known_color_crystals)

Comment: @Terriblefan Ah, cool. Thank you.